# Chip with long text in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the component `v-chip` from Vuetify, it cuts the text when the text is too long, is there any workaround for this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-chip>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita consectetur suscipit vel! Aliquam, temporibus laborum delectus ea architecto obcaecati laudantium eos sed ducimus cum error repellat voluptatum ullam fugit, officia sit laboriosam vero similique. Voluptatibus provident magnam libero facilis eum in, labore pariatur optio nesciunt culpa, delectus tenetur, sit quod praesentium? Iusto, non ipsam quis aliquid veniam aliquam placeat minima cupiditate expedita enim alias saepe vero autem. Voluptatum doloribus distinctio illo adipisci expedita, sequi maxime aut ratione magnam ipsum velit vero officia odio deserunt pariatur minima! At, magni aliquam! Ipsum impedit non quos fugiat veniam dolorem ad itaque necessitatibus voluptas?
    </v-chip>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: it fills the width. do you want it to wrap down on a new line?

Comment: @depperm yes i want that, note that even when it fills the width it doesn't show the full text because it's way too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add styles to v-chip like these:

> height: auto
>
> white-space: normal

hope it would help.

Answer (score 4):

To wrap the text:

```
.v-chip {
  height: auto !important;
}

.v-chip .v-chip__content {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 32px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of many alternates is that you can add an ellipsis and add full text to a title.So you see a truncated text and full text on hover

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-chip large>
      <span class="wrapclass" :title="txt">
          {{txt}}
      </span>
    </v-chip>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapclass {
  max-width: 99%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      txt: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita consectetur suscipit vel! Aliquam, temporibus laborum delectus ea architecto obcaecati laudantium eos sed ducimus cum error repellat voluptatum ullam fugit, officia sit laboriosam vero similique. Voluptatibus provident magnam libero facilis eum in, labore pariatur optio nesciunt culpa, delectus tenetur, sit quod praesentium? Iusto, non ipsam quis aliquid veniam aliquam placeat minima cupiditate expedita enim alias saepe vero autem. Voluptatum doloribus distinctio illo adipisci expedita, sequi maxime aut ratione magnam ipsum velit vero officia odio deserunt pariatur minima! At, magni aliquam! Ipsum impedit non quos fugiat veniam dolorem ad itaque necessitatibus voluptas?'
    }
  },
})
```

https://codepen.io/nizantz/pen/NWNWrJL

Answer (score 1):

Adding a class in v-chip might solve this

```
class="text-truncate"
```

This will truncate long text with a text ellipsis

more info here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/